# Unexplained behavior of NodeMapM (FGLGraph Library)

Tags: haskell

I'm going to represent arbitrary ariety relationships by a graph. In this way the context of each node would show all the relationships in which it is present. I started with properties, which are unary relations.

I found myself faced with a strange behavior of NodeMapM monad, which gives different results (**LEdges**) for sequences of functions that seem to me equivalent. Where am I wrong?

```
import Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph (empty)
import Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree
import Data.Graph.Inductive.NodeMap



p1 = ("P1", ['A','B','C','D'])
p2 = ("P2", ['B','C','E','F'])
p3 = ("P3", ['A','C','F','G'])

toLedges :: (a, [b]) -> [(b,b,a)]
toLedges (le,xs) = zipWith (\x1 x2 -> (x1,x2,le)) (init xs) (tail xs)


ex1 :: NodeMapM Char String Gr ()
ex1 = do insMapNodesM  (snd p1)
         insMapNodesM  (snd p2)
         insMapNodesM  (snd p3)
         insMapEdgesM  (toLedges p1)
         insMapEdgesM  (toLedges p2)
         insMapEdgesM  (toLedges p3)

-- run empty ex1 :: ((),(NodeMap Char, Gr Char String))

{-  (()
    , (NodeMap {map = fromList [('A',1),('B',2),('C',3),('D',4),('E',5),('F',6),('G',7)], key = 8}
      ,mkGraph [(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D'),(5,'E'),(6,'F'),(7,'G')]
               [(1,2,"P1"),(1,3,"P3"),(2,3,"P1"),(2,3,"P2"),(3,4,"P1"),(3,5,"P2"),(3,6,"P3"),(5,6,"P2"),(6,7,"P3")]
      )
    )
-}

ex2 :: NodeMapM Char String Gr ()
ex2 = do insMapNodesM  (snd p1)
         insMapEdgesM  (toLedges p1)
         insMapNodesM  (snd p2)
         insMapEdgesM  (toLedges p2)
         insMapNodesM  (snd p3)
         insMapEdgesM  (toLedges p3)

-- run empty ex2 :: ((),(NodeMap Char, Gr Char String))

{-  (()
    , (NodeMap {map = fromList [('A',1),('B',2),('C',3),('D',4),('E',5),('F',6),('G',7)], key = 8}
      ,mkGraph [(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D'),(5,'E'),(6,'F'),(7,'G')]
               [(1,3,"P3"),(2,3,"P2"),(3,6,"P3"),(5,6,"P2"),(6,7,"P3")]
      )
    )
-}
```

Comment: If you tried to minimize this (as I did) I think you would have been able to diagnose the problem yourself. You really should try to make that a habit -- you'll get much better at debugging things pretty much instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-adding a node deletes all edges out of that node. See [the source of `insNode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.7.0.1/docs/src/Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph.html#insNode), which is what `insMapNodesM` eventually calls:

```
insNode (v,l) = (([],v,l,[])&)
```

The two empty lists are for incoming and outgoing edges.

This... seems like an unfortunate behavior for `insMapNodesM` to me. I doubt very much you'll get them to change it now, though; backwards-compatibility concerns would make me nervous about changing that behavior in a library which has been "in the wild" for so long.